# Monitoring app launches on android

Tags: android

I need to create an app that is able to check when other apps are opened or closed ("on resume" or "on pause") on the device. I need to check the time of use of each app.

Can I do it without root access in the device?

Comment: No. I know some apps (like GO Cleaner) that allow you to kill other app's processes require root access, but Samsung tablets for example come with an app for just that which runs fine even if the device is not rooted. **How** to do that, though... I wish I could help you with that =\

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++){
        if(procInfos.get(i).processName.equals("com.android.browser")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Browser is running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

find the package name using download package name viewer

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gijoon.pkgnameviewer&hl=en